# How should I handle non-translated text under several language URLs?

Tags: google-translate

I am currently working on a project where I will have some pages translated entirely (meta-information on the project) and some pages (articles) only in one language, but still with the interface in many languages.

How should I handle this with regard to Google etc.?

I want the information to be available in all languages, so that people can find it with search terms in their local language, but can I get duplicate content problems if the articles are available on /fr/my-nice-article /de/my-nice-article with the same article text (not translated) and only translated interface ("Ecris un commentaire", "Schreibe einen Kommentar").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something [directly from Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=182192)

> Websites that provide content for different regions and in different
>   languages sometimes create content that is the same or similar but
>   available on different URLs. This is generally not a problem as long
>   as the content is for different users in different countries. While we
>   strongly recommend that you provide unique content for each different
>   group of users, we understand that this may not always be possible.
>   There is generally no need to "hide" the duplicates by disallowing
>   crawling in a robots.txt file or by using a "noindex" robots meta tag.
>   However, if you're providing the same content to the same users on
>   different URLs (for instance, if both example.de/ and example.com/de/
>   show German language content for users in Germany), you should pick a
>   preferred version and redirect (or use the rel=canonical link element)
>   appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Google automatically determines what language your content is written in. It users the language of the majority of all text. If you want to explicitly specify it, you can use the following snippet:

```
<meta name="language" content="de" />
```

Google, of course, shows only the pages in the user's language (so German Google users only see the `de`-content).